# Inferring return type of function based on inferred parameter object value types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've got a function that takes in a key, an object, and returns the value of that key in said object. In the event of a string union, I'd like the object to contain all the members of that union as keys.

The function currently looks like this:

```
const getValue = <T extends string>(key: T) => <O extends { [key in T]: unknown }>(obj: O): O[T] => {
    return obj[key];
};
```

When given a string union of defined keys, this function works as expected:

```
const key = "A" as "A" | "B" | "C";

// Correctly typed as number | boolean
const value = getValue(key)({
    A: 2,
    B: 1,
    C: true
});
```

However, I'd like this function to also gracefully handle `string`, in which case should add `undefined` as a possible return type, i.e.

```
// Value should be number | boolean | undefined, but is unknown
const otherValue = getValue(key as string)({
    A: 2,
    B: 1,
    C: true
});
```

I've tried looking into various solutions including `infer` usage, but haven't managed to find a solution so far. Is what I'm looking for possible in TypeScript?

Thanks for your time in helping out!

[For your convenience, here's a TypeScript Playground link with the above code.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGEFcCdoUwHYBdQEMlLgWwA4vaAGaQIDGSAlgPYIA0oAzlVnEgBYUIDmobc8oBHDgATBqCRVQpNqm5wAUKRoMUXVgDVUAG0hxQAXlAAeACqg4AD0wIxjJNE5cAfAAoA1nACeALlCmASkNnEwB5C2tEOwBvUABtTy9QTn8AXT8SdwQqAHcEUABfNyoAIwArP1CAyrjTVODQaIVQFtB4JBh80rKE71SAbgUCwaUVFETDUAAiAEEptHFZ%20YAfaYAhFenwKZGQCCpYOHJtJKQvHFEFwUgsEv5QVZKqKm04OVGEVVAANx09SfUSC0ujgHm8AVcTVaoBmfgATLRmq01n4AIyI6HgPwOPRDAK7MDA-4MNhUSDaESgO7XW73R7PV5yB6gEgiOCETiieglSAoCjiTLZPIfL5Udj8In6IyAyVgpKocSqRzcCFQ1qw0AIpEtFGgdHaiDY6C4gr4oA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We only need to change the return type to cover a specific case when `T` is a broad `string` type:

```
string extends T ? O[keyof O] | undefined : O[T]
```

If it is `string`, then we get all the values of `O` and add `undefined`.

Looks good!

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mppBgm)

Comment: Oh wow, that did the trick! I never thought about using `string extends T`, but that makes a lot of sense now that I think about it. Seems I've still got a lot to learn about Typescript...

Thanks for your help!